# Granular control over site styles with css

Tags: php, mysql, css, styles

I've been trying to wrap my head around a good way to do this, but so far have come up empty, and needed some guidance.

Basically, what I have at the moment is a style selector,  which gives 10 pre defined styles for the site that a user can choose from. Most of them are grotesque, and are merely proof of concept.

This is controlled by PHP and mysql. When a user logs in, and slects a non-default style, it is added against their user record in the DB. The site then refreshes, and loads the selected style.

It works really well, but now I want to try and have some granular control. For example, I would like users to be able to pick their own header background colour, heading text colour, sub heading colour and some font sizes.

It is a fairly trivial thing, and if I can't find a way to implement it, then so be it.

My initial thought was to have a table that has columns for each customizable part of the size, e.g. font size, colours etc. In the table, would be a record for each user. They then use some interface to pick and choose what they want, and then add it to the table.

My issue, was then what to do with the values that I retrieve from the DB. I would have liked to insert them straight into a CSS file, but I don't think this is possible without some server configuration changes, that I couldnt get to work.

So does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this, if there is any way at all.

Regards
Eds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to do this.

You may specify CSS properties directly in the `style` attribute of HTML tags, but that can quickly become tedious as you might have to insert code in scattered areas in the middle of your content, making maintenance harder.

You can also put all style definitions between `<style></style>` tags inside the `<head>` section, which partly eliminates the disadvantage of mixing content with presentation.

Finally, it is also possible to produce CSS files with PHP using database informations. Rename your stylesheet ***something*.php**, then put this at the top of the file :

```
<?php header('content-type: text/css'); ?>
```

This tells PHP that the content it will generate needs to be sent as a CSS file, so that the user's browser knows that it's a stylesheet. All that's left to do is to correctly reference your "mutable" stylesheet in the PHP script that holds your HTML content :

```
<link href="../layout/css/something.php" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

This will allow you to use this kind of things in your "CSS" file :

```
body
{
  background-color:
  <?php echo $userstyle['color']; // Retrieved from database somewhere above ?>;
}
```

However, if you care about performance, the latter solution may need some improvement using the *Cache-control* header, to avoid reloading the CSS file whenever the user follows a link in your website.

Comment: I was just about to add an answer myself, as i eventually found some more info on this. This should work perfectly! I will have to look into cache-control aswell. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious option to me would be to build a PHP script that would generate the stylesheet on the fly. This would only get called if there is a record in the table for that specific user that holds all the user-specific styles.

So for example, between your `<head></head>` you could put:

```
<?php if($user_has_style): ?><link rel="stylesheet" href="user_style.php" /><? endif; ?>
```

This calls the `user_style.php` script and generates the stylesheet needed.
You will have to add the correct headers to the output of the PHP stylesheet, which are:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

This website might be of some use, if you choose this method: http://mou.me.uk/2008/08/03/generating-dynamic-stylesheets-on-the-fly-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

You can put CSS into html file in two ways. You can either put the code in the header under `<style>` tag or you can put css on a specific item like `<body style="background-image:url('file.png')">`. Both ways you do not need css file that is separated from .html file :)

Comment: I did think about this, but then I would end up with PHP on each element in my page, and would have to go through each and every page and add the same php code to each one. It would work, but if that is my only option, I dont think it is worth the time, haha.

Comment: I then must really question the structure of your project. If you repeat background and similar stuff on every page, then it makes no sense and you should redo it properly. Things that are repeated more than once should be in classes or files and only called/included once. Thus you will need to do the actions, which I wrote about above, only once.

Comment: That's exactly right. Unless i misunderstood your answer, you were saying to add style inline to each HTML tag. My structure is currently central, and most, if not all of my style is controlled by several css files. I wanted to keep this centralisation.

Comment: I did not mean `each` in anywhere in my sentence. If you have the css/html centralized, my answer fits your needs perfectly. Just put (either way I said) the customized css (loaded from database) to override the defaults :)

Comment: sorry, must have misunderstood what you meant